# Insert into a backup table based on date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My table in Oracle 11g has 6 fields. I also have a backup table also with no values. The original table has 2 date values. I need to insert into the backup table from the original table the orders having an order-date 5 months back as of today.

The table has a field names ORDER-DATE and has records entered inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into backup_table
select * from original_table
where order-data > add_months(sysdate,-5);
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you so much. I have on small doubt. What is this "add_months" in the above query.. is it a keyword? Can u please explain?

Comment: add_months is a built-in function in Oracle SQL.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm) for details.